# The operation couldn’t be completed. (CHSErrorDomain error 1300.)

Tags: xcode, widgetkit

I'm trying to preview my widget I've made in Xcode, and I'm getting the following error:

```
RemoteHumanReadableError

ProcessError: Failed to launch widget extension: The operation couldn’t be completed. (CHSErrorDomain error 1300.)
```

I can't find anything on the internet related to it at all, so I've come here.
Any help will be appreciated.

I've tried rebooting, restarting & cleaning the Xcode build folder and using DevCleaner to clean ALL of Xcode's cache

Update: This only will happen if I have my `.previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))` added to my preview. If I don't, it builds perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving this by editing my Build Phases settings.

`Your Project` > `<Widget Extension>` > `Build Phases` > `Embed App Extensions` > Unchecked 'copy only when installing'

Went back to previews and they loaded no trouble.

Comment: I just added Widget Extension to my project target -> Build Phases > Embed App Extensions and preview works

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it was fixed by disabling Xcode rosetta mode.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem either and solved it in other ways. I created a `new scheme`, and selected the widget extension as its target. After selecting this scheme as current scheme, I retried preview and it worked.